# Cannot save data returned from fetch on a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to get a certain return value (of type string) from `fetch()` but I'm failing, although the data is there when I try to display it on console.
**The thing is that I need to do in a "function Component"**. That means it works in a "class Component" with setState.
Here is the code : too simple

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
 
function ProfilePhoto(props) {
    const [data,setData]=useState(()=>fetch(url)
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        return data.userPhoto;}));

    return (
        <div>
            {"data: "+data}
             <input  id="picture" type="file" name="file" />
                <img src={"./images/"+ data}></img>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProfilePhoto;
```

Data in console:

> {id: 1, username: 'Paul', userPhoto: 'photo1.jpg', posts: Array(4), login: null, …}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch data and store it to state, I suggest using `useEffect`.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
 
function ProfilePhoto(props) {
    const [data,setData]=useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(url)
      .then((response)=>response.json())
      .then((newData)=>{
          console.log(newData);
          setData(newData)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {"data: "+data}
             <input  id="picture" type="file" name="file" />
                <img src={"./images/"+ data}></img>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProfilePhoto;
```

Passing an empty array `[]` as the second parameter of `useEffect` tells it to run the function in the first parameter once, after the component is initially rendered. Then you can update state using `setData`. The problem is you are trying to set the initial value of useState to an unresolved promise. It will not update the state after the promise resolves unless you use `setData`.